# Reading in specific columns from a log file in python

Tags: python, readfile

I am trying to read in this file using Python, however I keep getting `ValueError: Need more than 0 values to unpack`. Wondering if anyone can help?

I need to read in this file and select specific columns, so that I can later put these values onto a highchart graph.

In the file, the first line is empty, which is what I think may be causing this error, but I'm not sure how to resolve this. This is what the file looks like:

> Wed Apr 23 00:00:13 GMT 2014
>   ID   USER  PR NUM    VIR    RE   MEH  S   CPU    MM    TIMESTA  INFO
>   1555 root  19   0  3162m  1.7g  8192  S  34.6  22.1  955:04.48  resource
>   1566 nobody  19   0  2172m  2.9g  8192  S  22.6  33.1  955:04.48  resource2

This is the code I am using at the minute:

```
import csv

r = csv.reader(open("C:/test.log"))

ID = []
user = []
PR =[]
NUM = []
VIR = []
RE = []
MEH = []
S = []
CPU = []
MM = []
TIMESTA = []
INFO = []

for ID, user, PR, NUM, VIR, RE, MEH, S, CPU, MM, TIMESTA, INFO in r:
    ID.append(ID)
    user.append(user)
    PR.append(PR)
    NUM.append(NUM)
    VIR.append(VIR)
    RE.append(RE)
    MEH.append(MEH)
    S.append(S)
    CPU.append(CPU)
    MM.append(MM)
    TIMESTA.append(TIMESTA)
    INFO.append(INFO)

print ID, CPU, MM, INFO
```

Thanks

Comment: The lines aren't the same so you can't treat them as the same.  Read the whole file in with readlines() then take a look at the first two if you need them, or otherwise skip them and parse the rest of them. This way you can count the entries, and check that each line has all fields.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can't name the temporary values in your for-loop the same as the lists in which you want to store the information. Also that log file is not a CSV file. CSV means comma separated values, e.g.

```
a, b, c
```

What you want is something like this.

```
log = open('C:/test.log', 'r').read().splitlines() # read the file, split by line, and remove extraneous whitespace.
log = log[2:] # get rid of 1st and second lines.
log = [line.split(' ') for line in log] # split each line by spaces
ID = []
users = []
# etc.
for line in log:
    ID.append(line[0])
    users.append(line[1])
    # etc.
```

I didn't test this, but it should work :) Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks! I tried out the code, but I seem to be getting an Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'.

Comment: sorry. get rid of the strip() function in the first line.

Comment: Also, if this is for homework you might want to get rid of that list comprehension (Google is your friend). Most beginners of python don't use them much ;)

Comment: Actually, just noticing, when I run this code, if I want to print out all of the users, I added print users onto the end of the code. And it prints ['1555', 'nobody']. If you look at the contents from the file above, '1555' is the ID of the first line and 'nobody' is user of the second line. Is there anyway I can fix this so that when I print users, it returns ['root', 'nobody']?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do like this.

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

rs = csv.reader(open("C:/test.log", 'rb'), delimiter=' ')

IDs      = []
users    = []
PRs      = []
NUMs     = []
VIRs     = []
REs      = []
MEHs     = []
Ss       = []
CPUs     = []
MMs      = []
TIMESTAs = []
INFOs    = []

for ID, user, PR, NUM, VIR, RE, MEH, S, CPU, MM, TIMESTA, INFO in islice(rs, 2, None):
    IDs.append(ID)
    users.append(user)
    PRs.append(PR)
    NUMs.append(NUM)
    VIRs.append(VIR)
    REs.append(RE)
    MEHs.append(MEH)
    Ss.append(S)
    CPUs.append(CPU)
    MMs.append(MM)
    TIMESTAs.append(TIMESTA)
    INFOs.append(INFO)

print IDs, CPUs, MMs, INFOs
```

input(test.log):

```
Wed Apr 23 00:00:13 GMT 2014
ID USER PR NUM VIR RE MEH S CPU MM TIMESTA INFO
1555 root 19 0 3162m 1.7g 8192 S 34.6 22.1 955:04.48 resource
1566 nobody 19 0 2172m 2.9g 8192 S 22.6 33.1 955:04.48 resource2
```

output:

```
['1555', '1566'] ['34.6', '22.6'] ['22.1', '33.1'] ['resource', 'resource2']
```

Comment: @user3216736: If you upload `test.log`, I can advise precisely.